# Survey that collects anonymous results, but tracks which recipient have responded

Tags: data-science, google-forms, survey, data-collection

I was trying to create a survey where the recipients could anonymously submit their responses. However, on my end I wanted to be able to track who hadn't took the survey so that I could email a follow up. I don't want to see which emails/names have which responses. I'm also sending this survey to a lot of people, around 50 each month for now. I've researched and tested many different ways and I'm at a loss, so any help or tips is appreciated.

I don't mind if the solution is a paid service or not, just as long as I could do this easily. Thank you!

I've tried typeform, which is anonymous and had an article called "how to identify your respondents". It however had a solution where the end result was you could see who responded to what question.
SurveyMonkey also has a "Respondent ID" that it attaches to each survey even when it's anonymous, but this wasn't helpful as what I needed was emails.
A solution I found for Google forms was generated pre-filled links, but this again shows me who responded to what. It also would have been too cumbersome to do each time I would send this out to 50 or so people.
Every other survey service I tried stated that that this was impossible.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you distribute the links to your form.
Using Typeform should work fine.

You could pass the respondent's email address via [hidden fields](https://www.typeform.com/help/a/what-are-hidden-fields-360052676372/).
Link would be `https://form.typeform.com/to/abc123?email=nico@lol.com`

When the responses comes in, push them to a google sheet, and compare the list to see who has not answered yet.

But this defeats the purpose of anonymity. Instead, you should use unique ids.